# Accessing the class inside of the class

Tags: class, scala, object

Lets say I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
  val value = new MyClass
}
```

This doesn't work, it brings up a stack error.
Is there a way to make this work, so value is an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: What's the value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of value of v...

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to make this possible is with a `lazy val`, which is not executed until it is accessed:

```
scala> class MyClass { lazy val value = new MyClass }
defined class MyClass

scala> new MyClass
res0: MyClass = MyClass@6a073b72

scala> res0.value
res1: MyClass = MyClass@6b37008a

scala> res1.value
res2: MyClass = MyClass@503f0b70
```

Comment: Please don't help people writing such code, tell them this is not possible.

Comment: But it is possible ;). In this case it may not be good style but there are certainly use cases where this can be useful. I can't think of one now, maybe later.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you see that such construct would recursively create an infinite number of `MyClass` objects.

If you really want such "chain" of `MyClass` objects, you need some form of base case to limit the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I have what you need

```
class MyClass {
  val value = this
}
```

however I am wondering what that could be useful for...